# Why do I see default search results on my search page?

Tags: search

I created a new search page on the global search center. I edited the search result webpart and selected a custom result source. The custom result source is using this query:

```
{SearchTerms} Path:http://archive.myCompany.com
```

When I go to my new search page I see there alot of results already. I didnt add some keyword or press on enter!! I would like to have 0 results by default. After I add some keyword and press on enter, I would like to show search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the search query in {? {your search query} } format.

For your case:

```
{?{SearchTerms} Path:http://archive.myCompany.com }
```

Here's the link to the technet article with explanation on narrowing search results using query transform:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn186229.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_How_does_query_transform_affect_query